# login using cookie session in cemerick/Friend

Tags: authentication, clojure, compojure

I am trying to integrate [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) into my [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) app.

I have implemented two functions : `auth/handle-authentication` and `auth/check-credential` that I use in the following code :

```
(defroutes app*
  (GET "/requires-authentication" req
       (friend/authenticated (str "You have successfully authenticated as "
                                  (friend/current-authentication)))))


(defn secured-routes
  "Takes a list of unsecure (public) routes
  and returns the same routes but with an authentication middleware
  (authorization still has to be handled for each route)"
  [unsecured-routes]
  (-> unsecured-routes
      (friend/authenticate
          {:allow-anon?             true
           :unauthenticated-handler auth/handle-authentication
           :credential-fn           auth/check-credential
           :workflows [(workflows/http-basic) ; not sure what to put here
                            (workflows/interactive-form)]
})))


(def api-middleware-config
  "Configure the middlewares of the API"
  {:params    {:urlencoded true
               :multipart  true
               :nested     true
               :keywordize true}
   :responses {:not-modified-responses true
               :absolute-redirects     true
               :content-types          true
               :default-charset        "utf-8"}})


(defroutes app

   ;; public routes (they work fine)
  (-> (....)

  ;; authentication required
  (-> (secured-routes app*)
      (wrap-defaults api-middleware-config)
       ...)
  )
```

`auth/check-credential` checks the basic auth string from the request. If correct, returns `{:identity username}`. It works, since with postman/curl I can use the basic auth and get "You have successfully authenticated as ..." as a response.

`auth/handle-authentication` takes the request and checks that the cookie is correct.
If it is, it then returns a map `{:identity "test"}`. This doesn't do anything, and regardless of the return value of my function (I tried hardcoding it). What am I missing ?

Note that my situation may be a bit specific since the login is done in another app, but the routes/endpoints are shared via nginx and I receive the cookie and have access to the sessions from a database. Checking the cookie is done in `auth/handle-authentication`.

How can I get `"You have successfully authenticated as ..."` from a browser with a valid cookie ? Right now I get a `200OK` with `application/octet` stream headers and an empty body (which triggers an empty file download in the browser). I don't really get the `:workflow`, or what `alow-anon?` does yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks somewhat strange to me. You assign `auth/handle-authentication` to `:unauthorized`, but the handler function assigned to `:unauthorized` is called when an incoming request could not be authorized.

If I understand you correctly, you want either basic auth or authentication by a third-party supplied cookie where this should be checked by your `auth/handle-authentication` method. If so, you need to ensure that this method is called as part of what you assign as a `:workflow` (cf. [Friend documentation on workflows](https://github.com/cemerick/friend#workflows)).
Basically, I think that you're looking for:

```
:workflows [(auth/handle-authentication) (workflows/http-basic)]
```

Adam Bard has recently written a blog post on [Easy custom auth in Clojure with Friend](http://adambard.com/blog/easy-auth-with-friend/), I guess this might help clarify.

Comment: You understand me correctly. Agreed it seemed weird to have it this way. Thanks I'll read the last link before getting back here. Isn't the syntax : `(workflows/http-basic        :credential-fn auth/handle-authentication)` (I tried that too) ?

Comment: No, credential functions are called typically by authentication functions. `(workflows/http-basic :credential-fn auth/handle-authentication)` would tell `http-basic` to hand over the parameters it extracted from the basic auth info (username, password) to your cookie checking method -- this is probably not what you want to do. The list with `http-basic` and your `handle-authentication` means that this both of these methods are available, the first to succeed would allow access. Probably you want the cookie check first, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Alright so the example is working locally, but not under my vagrant/nginx setup...